# How to Convert openai functions to PromptTemplate in langchain when using local llms?

Tags: python, openai-api, large-language-model, py-langchain

Is is possible to Convert openai functions to PromptTemplate in langchain when using local llms and return final output similar to openai api function format

```
import langchain
functions = [
        {
            "name": "get_current_weather",
            "description": "Get the current weather in a given location",
            "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "location": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA",
                    },
                    "unit": {"type": "string", "enum": ["celsius", "fahrenheit"]},
                },
                "required": ["location"],
            },
        }
    ]
llm = llm()

#Pass functions into prompt template in langchain 

#Format prompt template similar to openai manner
```

Comment: No, I created my own solution similar to Ollamafunction callling.